# Geometry shaders on Surface RT

Tags: directx, windows-8, geometry-shader

Can anyone tell me if geometry shaders are supported on the Microsoft Surface RT? On one hand, MSDN makes it sound like the Surface RT supports only feature level 9_1, and geometry [shaders are only available in feature levels >= 10_0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476876.aspx). On the other hand, [there's this guy](https://twitter.com/incendy/statuses/298128600362807296) saying:

> Jesse Barker @incendy
>   @dotMorten I am confused haha.. so my geometry shaders work on Surface rt?
>
> Morten Nielsen ‏@dotMorten
>   @incendy Yes ! They might run software emulation, but yes. That's why DX is so awesome. Don't worry about hardware. It'll work

Does anybody have actual experience with this? I don't have a Surface RT here to test with, so any guidance on this would be much appreciated.

Comment: No clue. I've got a Surface RT to potentially test with though. I'd have clue about how to get something up and running on it but I'd be glad to help if I can somehow!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Surface RT is indeed FEATURE_LEVEL_9_1, so hardware geometry shaders are unsupported.  The Windows software rasterizer, WARP, does support it though.  This could be what Morten is referring to.  To create a WARP device, use D3D_DRIVER_TYPE_WARP in your call to D3D11CreateDevice.  Note that on Surface RT, the performance of geometry shaders on WARP will not likely be adequate for real-time scenarios.